# Can I import a ".jar" to JSF and use It?

Tags: java, jsf

I've been reading posts and researching how I should implement the backend of my project, but I've never developed for the web before, so I'm having some trouble.

My project has two pieces:

- My frontend, (a single page), which is already implemented
- A third-party library to process text.

How do I connect them?

A simplified description of my project: the user enters text, and then presses a button. The program then uses javascript to perform some operations on the text, then this third party library will be called on the text as well.

The third-party library that I am using has 3 api flavors: C++, Java, and Python. I'm using Java (because I know Java, don't feel comfortable programming in C++, and don't know Python).

However, I'm not sure how to import the library .jar for use in a web app. Can I achieve this with JSF? And will JSF work with Bootstrap 3, JQuery UI 1.11.4 and the web components in my front-end page?

I looked into both JSF and Spring, and chose JSF because I want to keep my project simple, and Spring seems more complex. But I don't have experience with either framework.

Comment: The short answer is yes. I recommend you get starting with some tutorials. Normally I wouldn't suggest a third party library but http://primefaces.org/ is a great widget toolkit and has a lot of working examples. I really like JSF. There are a lot of other toolkits out there but it has, and will continue to be, my favorite for working quickly and having a sense of stability.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Drop your third party library (jar) in WEB-INF/lib folder. Then, from the `@ManagedBean`, add the call to the relevant classes/methods from the third party library.

E.g.

```
@ManagedBean
@ViewScoped
public class MyBean {
    private String data;
    //getter and setter for data
    public void foo() {
        ThirdPartyLibraryClass tplc = new ThirdPartyLibraryClass();
        tplc.bar(data);
    }
}
```

And in your view, make sure to fill `MyBean#data`. E.g.:

```html
<h:form>
    <h:inputText value="#{myBean.data}" />
    <h:commandButton value="Submit" action="#{myBean.foo}" />
</h:form>
```